# Is air combustible, or incombustible?

Tags: meaning, adjectives, terminology, science

I'm wondering if *air*—the everyday air we breathe, with oxygen, nitrogen, C0<sub>2</sub>, etc.—can be defined as either combustible or incombustible.

I would be inclined to say that our air is combustible, because incombustible gas would prevent a flame from lighting. However, the only part of air that is relevant to a flame is the oxygen, and combustion refers to an "exothermic reaction with oxygen", so I think technically oxygen is incombustible since it doesn't react with itself. Thus I'm not sure if it's accurate to say air is combustible, rather then simply allowing other objects to do so.

If I wanted to be 100% pedantic, which would be the most accurate term to use to describe our air, *combustible* or *incombustible*?

Comment: If air were combustible we'd all be in big trouble.  "Combustible", as you note, refers to a substance that oxidizes rapidly, releasing heat, but air is already oxidized (in a manner of speaking, at least).

Comment: What support do you have the incombustible gases cannot support combustion? Also, what do you define as "air"? Nitrogen, oxygen, and carbon dioxide?

Comment: Being pedantic, the terms _combustible_ / _incombustible_ are only applied in relation to a different substance in a normal atmosphere, so the question is inappropriate. The chemistry of the situation is that the oxygen and the nitrogen of the atmosphere _will_ react together under extreme conditions (a lightning bolt), but here again, the terms 'combustion' or 'burning' are inappropriate.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it requires specialized chemistry knowledge to answer. It should have been asked on [Chem.SE](chemistry.stackexchange.com) instead.

Comment: Air is a "combustive" (an oxidizing agent). Fuel is a "combustible".

Answer (score 2):

Combustible refers to something that [can catch fire](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/combustible). That this is in air is assumed. The other component (other than the fuel) of what we call fire (a rapid exothermic chemical reaction) is oxygen, which is always present in air (about 21% by volume).

I think what we would assume by the term 'air' is not combustible, but referring to it as incombustible is probably not useful. @Hank is correct in asking what you mean, exactly, by 'air'. You can find contaminated 'air' in some places such as [Yanar Dag](http://www.odditycentral.com/travel/yanar-dag-the-eternally-burning-mountain-of-azerbaijan.html) in Azerbaijan that burns by itself if ignited.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a discussion of "is air combustable": http://scienceline.ucsb.edu/getkey.php?key=954

Combustion is generally defined as rapid oxidation.  Air itself is incombustible.  The Oxygen portion of air is an oxidation agent, it does not oxidize itself, it oxidizes other things, so will not burn or be a part of the action of burning even at 100% pure oxygen, there must be a combustible target also present.

I would say it would be acceptable to call oxygen itself an accelerator, but incombustible, and air definitely is incombustible.

Comment: What do you mean by 'Air itself is inflammable/incombustible.'?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  Sorry, was self editing and got interrupted, fail to fix.  Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

The *air* most refer to is 78% nitrogen, 21% oxygen, and 1% carbon dioxide, argon, and other gases. So let's just say, for example purposes, that it's mainly nitrogen and oxygen.

Nitrogen is **not combustible** so we'll address oxygen.

Oxygen itself won't combust without an activation energy. This mainly comes into play with pure oxygen tanks used by hospitals and ambulances.

**So, will the air we breath every combust?**

Per [USBC](http://scienceline.ucsb.edu/getkey.php?key=954), *Oxygen is also not flammable, but it is a high-energy gas that very readily oxidizes other materials.* For something to burn, the reaction requires an oxidizer, like **oxygen**, and a fuel source. Since the air itself is not flammable, it does fill the fuel category. Thus, without a fuel source, it will not combust, spontaneous or otherwise.

Air fills the **combustion support** role, but is not combustible, because air itself does not burn.

Comment: Oxygen will react with nitrogen, and does, in the atmosphere. A large activation energy prevents large-scale reaction.